# Does $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ exists, when $f(x)=0$ for all $x \leq 0$ and $f(x)=1$ otherwise?

Tags: real-analysis

Logically, one has to study the limit from both sides of $0$ on the x-axis.

Intuitively $f(x)$ approaches $0$ when $x$ approaches $0$ from the left. But from the other side it is a bit trickier. What happens? Does the limit of $f(x)$, when $x$ approaches $0$ from the right, exist? If so, what is its value? What can be said about the limit in general, meaning from both sides combined?

Also, how does one write (mathematically) the criteria for the existence of such a limit? Does it include $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ - related concepts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x) $ would equal 0, and $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)$ equals 1. Although the left and right limits *exist* individually, the $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ would not exist because the two are not equal.

Comment: Compactly:  $f(0-) = 0 \neq 1 = f(0+)$. +1 for you.

Comment: Aha okay, this makes sense. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Tarvish's answer is correct; I would add to his answer to answer

> Also, how does one write (mathematically) the criteria for the existence of such a limit? Does it include ϵ and δ - related concepts?

If a function $f$ is defined in some neighbourhood of a point $c$, and that there is a number N, such that for all $\epsilon \gt 0$, there exists a $\delta \gt 0$, and that $\lvert f(x)-N \rvert \lt \epsilon$ as long as

i) $0 \lt x - c \lt \delta$; then we say that $f$ has a right limit at point $c$, and write $\lim _{x \to c ^+} f(x) = N$ or $f(c+)=N$. (1)

ii) $0 \lt c - x \lt \delta$; then we say that $f$ has a left limit at point $c$, and write $\lim _{x \to c ^-} f(x) = N$ or $f(c-)=N$. (2)

**A function has a limit at a point if and only if it has both a left and a right limit at that point, and that its left and right limit are equal.** (A)

Some useless info:

(A) **Proof**

Suppose that $f$ has both left and right limit at a point $c$, and they are both equal to $N$. We claim that $\lim _{x \to c} f(x) = N$, and will show that there is a $\delta \gt 0$ for all $\epsilon \gt 0$ such that $\lvert f(x)-N \rvert\lt \epsilon$ as long as $\lvert x - c \rvert \lt \delta$.

For a $\epsilon \gt 0$, let $\delta_1$ be the $\delta$ in (1), and $\delta_2$ be the one in (2). Let $\delta = \min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$. Now one can see that $\lvert f(x)-N \rvert\lt \epsilon$ as long as $\lvert x - c \rvert \lt \delta$. $\square$

Answer (score 0):

No.

If the limit exists when $x\to 0$, then for every sequence $a_n$ such that $a_n\to0$, then $\lim(a_n)$ must exist and be the same value.

If you choose a sequence of negative values, then $\lim(a_n)=0$, but if you choose a sequence of positive values, then $\lim(a_n)=1$. This is a contradiction